# Config is required for persistReducer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

Im new to react native and I'm trying to create a sample project with redux persist. Im getting this below error and I'm not even sure where this is coming from.

Im running using Expo and for persist im using @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

This is my persistConfig:

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ['bookmarks']
};
```

Initializing

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ 
    booksReducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, booksReducer) 
});
```

[image: Error message while running using expo]

Comment: Can you add the supporting code where you initialize the reducer with the config?

Comment: @Baily I've updated the question, is that what you mean by initializing?